# How to Draw a simple GUI Histogram

Tags: java, project, histogram

I need to draw a simple histogram for a project I'm working on that needs to look this...

[image: Histogram]

I know there is got to be some simple for loop to run on my H[] array which consists of how many pixels belong to each gray scale value... so in H[] we have lets say "10 pixels in gray scale value 1" so at 1 there would be a line of length 10 going vertically next to my image...

if anyone could offer their help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks.

wrote this but its too big and upside down and angled for some reason.

```
         if (H != null) {
                    int width = getWidth();
                    int height = getHeight();           
                    int HhPos = (width - (width/2));
                    int HvPos = (height - (height));
                  for(int i = 0 ; i <255 ; i++){
                     g.drawRect(i+HhPos, i+HvPos, 1, H[i]);


                   }
```

Comment: You should try using a lib just to plot this type of chart. A good one for Java desktop (is that your case?) is [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).

Comment: I'd rather just use a for loop to go through my array, im not familiar with JFreeChart.

Comment: well I wrote this, but it's too big and you cant see the whole thing... plus its upside down.   (code above in edited OP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gilbert said, you need to normalize you values, to determine the maximum range or ceiling.

From this you can then determine the percentage of a given value compared to the maximum and then plot it on the graph, based on the available height.

(Taken from the [previous answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518496/drawing-a-graphical-histogram/12520104#12520104))

```
// Determine the maximum vertical value...
int maxValue = 0;

for (Integer key : mapHistory.keySet()) {
    int value = mapHistory.get(key);
    maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, value);
}

int xPos = xOffset;

for (Integer key : mapHistory.keySet()) {
    int value = mapHistory.get(key);
    // Calculate the percentage that the given value uses compared to that of the
    // maximum value
    float percentage = (float)value / (float)maxValue;
    // Calculate the line height based on the available vertical space...
    int barHeight = Math.round(percentage * height);
    g2d.setColor(new Color(key, key, key));

    int yPos = height + yOffset - barHeight;
    Rectangle2D bar = new Rectangle2D.Float(xPos, yPos, barWidth, barHeight);

    g2d.fill(bar);
    g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g2d.draw(bar);

    xPos += barWidth;
}
```

Now in the previous example, I used a `Map` to to store the values, but it should relativly easy to replace that with your data array...

`for (Integer key : mapHistory.keySet())` would become `for (int key : H)`

Also, with `Graphics.drawLine`, it is drawing a line from one point to another, not one point to a width/height value (like say `Graphics.drawRectangle`)

Comment: thank you this helps a lot... how can i clear the histogram when i load a new image though?

Comment: nvm i got it except now the graph is too wide to fit in the window :(

Comment: Yeah, eventually that's gaining to happen. You can only make the bars so wide. You could use the same technique you used to calculate the height with the width. You know how wide the area is, you know how many bars you have. Something like width / barCount, make sure you allow for values < 0 though

Answer (score 0):

You're plotting points that have an x and y value.  You're drawing a histogram that has a width and height in pixels.

For example, let's say your histogram is 500 pixels in width, and 300 pixels in height.

You go through your data points once, looking for the minimum x, minimum y, maximum x, and maximum y.

Assuming we're plotting Y points (the X axis is the width), you subtract the minimum x from the maximum x.  Divide 500 pixels (the width) by the difference, and you get the number of pixels per x value.  This number can be greater than one, so you have more than one pixel per x value.  This number can be less than one, so you have more data values than pixels.

```
width pixels per value = width of histogram in pixels / difference in X points
```

You do the same for the Y axis.  Calculate the pixels per y value.

```
height pixels per value = height of histogram in pixels / difference in y points
```

Now, you go through your data points a second time.  For each data point, you calculate the width and height in pixels from the x and y value of the data point.  You use the number of pixels per value for both the width and the height to make the conversion.

```
width = x value * width pixels per value

height = y value * height pixels per value
```

You use the Java `Graphics` `drawLine` or `drawRect` method to draw the line or bar in your histogram.  Just remember that the Y dimension in Java graphics goes down, rather than up like in your histograph.  You'll have to take this into account when you're drawing.