# Custom graph - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, graph, jfreechart

I'm trying to create a custom dynamic histogram type bar graph in Java. I've searched a lot but coudn't find a way to achieve this.

I'm aware of the [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/index.html) library but it doesn't meet my needs. This is what the JFreeChart histogram looks like :

[image]

But what I want is a dyanamic Histogram with just X-axis. 
This photoshopped image will make it easier to understand. 
[image]

The JFrame will have fixed boundaries. As you can see, there should be no Y-axis. The bars' height should adjust automatically based on the values.

Please help me build this! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518496/drawing-a-graphical-histogram/12520104#12520104) for a starting point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A poor man's histogram:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class HistogramPanel extends JPanel
{
    private int histogramHeight = 200;
    private int barWidth = 50;
    private int barGap = 10;

    private JPanel barPanel;
    private JPanel labelPanel;

    private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();

    public HistogramPanel()
    {
        setBorder( new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10) );
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        barPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(1, 0, barGap, 0) );
        Border outer = new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK);
        Border inner = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 10);
        Border compound = new CompoundBorder(outer, inner);
        barPanel.setBorder( compound );

        labelPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(1, 0, barGap, 0) );
        labelPanel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(5, 10, 0, 10) );

        add(barPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void addHistogramColumn(String label, int value, Color color)
    {
        Bar bar = new Bar(label, value, color);
        bars.add( bar );
    }

    public void layoutHistogram()
    {
        barPanel.removeAll();
        labelPanel.removeAll();

        int maxValue = 0;

        for (Bar bar: bars)
            maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, bar.getValue());

        for (Bar bar: bars)
        {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(bar.getValue() + "");
            label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
            label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);
            int barHeight = (bar.getValue() * histogramHeight) / maxValue;
            Icon icon = new ColorIcon(bar.getColor(), barWidth, barHeight);
            label.setIcon( icon );
            barPanel.add( label );

            JLabel barLabel = new JLabel( bar.getLabel() );
            barLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            labelPanel.add( barLabel );
        }
    }

    private class Bar
    {
        private String label;
        private int value;
        private Color color;

        public Bar(String label, int value, Color color)
        {
            this.label = label;
            this.value = value;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public String getLabel()
        {
            return label;
        }

        public int getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public Color getColor()
        {
            return color;
        }
    }

    private class ColorIcon implements Icon
    {
        private int shadow = 3;

        private Color color;
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public ColorIcon(Color color, int width, int height)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int getIconWidth()
        {
            return width;
        }

        public int getIconHeight()
        {
            return height;
        }

        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
        {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width - shadow, height);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillRect(x + width - shadow, y + shadow, shadow, height - shadow);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel();
        panel.addHistogramColumn("A", 350, Color.RED);
        panel.addHistogramColumn("B", 690, Color.YELLOW);
        panel.addHistogramColumn("C", 510, Color.BLUE);
        panel.addHistogramColumn("D", 570, Color.ORANGE);
        panel.addHistogramColumn("E", 180, Color.MAGENTA);
        panel.addHistogramColumn("F", 504, Color.CYAN);
        panel.layoutHistogram();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Histogram Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( panel );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to add this histogram to a JPanel of a JFrame that is in another class (which is in the same package). When I use `panel.add(new Histogram());`, the histogram doesn't show up. Can you please walk me through this?

Comment: @camickr Please help ^^

Comment: You can't use `panel.add(new Histogram());`. First of all the class is HistogramPanel. Secondly you don't have a reference to the HistogramPanel, so how can you invoke the `addHistogramColumn(...)` method to add the bars to the panel?

Comment: Okay I understand. But what do I do now? How do I add this histogram to a jpanel of another class? Please help me. I'm new to this. Thanks in advance! @camickr

Comment: The same way you add any component to the panel of another class. I gave you the 5 basic lines of code to create the Histogram. Then you just add the Histogram to whatever panel you want.

Comment: @ChinmayDabke, I updated the code example so that the histograms now have a shadow border so it looks more like the JFreeChart example.

Answer (score 4):

I'd give [`JFreeChart`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info) a second look. You can make the range axis invisible and use item labels instead. Absent a legend, overriding `getItemPaint()` can supply arbitrary colors. An alternative approach is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Paint;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.ItemLabelAnchor;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.ItemLabelPosition;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StandardBarPainter;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.TextAnchor;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29709153/230513
 */
public class BarChart {

    private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        String row = "Row";
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(350, row, "A");
        dataset.addValue(690, row, "B");
        dataset.addValue(510, row, "C");
        dataset.addValue(570, row, "D");
        dataset.addValue(180, row, "E");
        dataset.addValue(504, row, "F");
        return dataset;
    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {
        CategoryAxis categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis("");
        ValueAxis valueAxis = new NumberAxis("");
        valueAxis.setVisible(false);
        BarRenderer renderer = new BarRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int column) {
                switch (column) {
                    case 0:
                        return Color.red;
                    case 1:
                        return Color.yellow;
                    case 2:
                        return Color.blue;
                    case 3:
                        return Color.orange;
                    case 4:
                        return Color.gray;
                    case 5:
                        return Color.green.darker();
                    default:
                        return Color.red;
                }
            }
        };
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
        renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(
            ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12, TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER));
        renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(Boolean.TRUE);
        renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
        CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, categoryAxis, valueAxis, renderer);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, false);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
        return chart;
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("BarChart");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(createChart(createDataset())));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new BarChart().display();
        });
    }
}
```