# How to create Stacked bar chart Date time Category

Tags: java, jfreechart

I expect to create Status chart like this [image]

However I cant XAXis Category was rendered incorrectly.
[image]
Here is my code I studied from [JFreeChart - horizontal stacked bar chart with date axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105094/jfreechart-horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-with-date-axis)

```
private static final String STANDBY_SERIES = "STANDBY";
private static final String HEATING_SERIES = "HEATING";
private static final String HOLDING_SERIES = "HOLDING";
private static final String COOLING_SERIES = "COOLING";
private static final String LOWERING_SERIES = "LOWERING";

private static final int STANDBY_SERIES_INDEX = 0;
private static final int HEATING_SERIES_INDEX = 1;
private static final int HOLDING_SERIES_INDEX = 2;
private static final int COOLING_SERIES_INDEX = 3;
private static final int LOWERING_SERIES_INDEX = 4;

private static final Color STANDBY_COLOR = Color.DARK_GRAY;
private static final Color HEATING_COLOR = Color.ORANGE;
private static final Color HOLDING_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
private static final Color COOLING_COLOR = Color.CYAN;
private static final Color LOWERING_COLOR = Color.GREEN;

ArrayList<EventStatus> testData = null;
CategoryPlot plot;
private Long Datetolong(String date)
{
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
Date inputDate = null;
try {
    inputDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
    System.out.println(inputDate.getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();}   
return inputDate.getTime();
}
    public StackedTimeBarChart(String title) {
    super(title);
    // set up some test data
    initData();

    // set the start and end date of the chart
    plot = new CategoryPlot();
    plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
    plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);

    // create dataset
    CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();

    // create the axis
    CategoryAxis catAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    DateAxis dateAxis = new DateAxis();
    dateAxis.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
    //dateAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.HOUR, 1));
    dateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"));

    // set up the renderer
    StackedBarRenderer rend = new StackedBarRenderer();
    //rend.setBase(chartRange.getLowerBound());
    rend.setSeriesPaint(STANDBY_SERIES_INDEX, STANDBY_COLOR);
    rend.setSeriesPaint(HEATING_SERIES_INDEX, HEATING_COLOR);
    rend.setSeriesPaint(HOLDING_SERIES_INDEX, HOLDING_COLOR);
    rend.setSeriesPaint(COOLING_SERIES_INDEX, COOLING_COLOR);
    rend.setSeriesPaint(LOWERING_SERIES_INDEX, LOWERING_COLOR);

    // set up the plot
    plot.setDataset(dataset);
    plot.setDomainAxis(catAxis);
    plot.setRangeAxis(dateAxis);
    plot.setRenderer(rend);

    // create the chart and add it
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 450));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
}

private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    Date chartStartDate = new Date(testData.get(0).getTime());
    Date chartEndDate = new Date(testData.get(testData.size() - 1).getTime());
    Range chartRange = new Range(chartStartDate.getTime(), chartEndDate.getTime());
    if (testData != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < testData.size(); i++) {
            // is there data?
            if (testData.size() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < testData.size(); j++) {
                    EventStatus es = testData.get(j);
                    long eventTime = es.getTime();
                    int status = es.getStatus();
                    String name = es.getName();

                    // if data event time is in the range of the chart then show it
                    // THIS DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY!!!!
                    if (eventTime >= chartStartDate.getTime() && eventTime < chartEndDate.getTime()) {
                        // create series and categories
                        if (es.getStatus() == STANDBY_SERIES_INDEX) {
                            dataset.addValue(new Double(es.getTime()), STANDBY_SERIES, es.getName());
                        } else if (es.getStatus() == HEATING_SERIES_INDEX) {
                            dataset.addValue(new Double(es.getTime()), HEATING_SERIES, es.getName());
                        } else if (es.getStatus() == HOLDING_SERIES_INDEX) {
                            dataset.addValue(new Double(es.getTime()), HOLDING_SERIES, es.getName());
                        } else if (es.getStatus() == COOLING_SERIES_INDEX) {
                            dataset.addValue(new Double(es.getTime()), COOLING_SERIES, es.getName());
                        } else if (es.getStatus() == LOWERING_SERIES_INDEX) {
                            dataset.addValue(new Double(es.getTime()), LOWERING_SERIES, es.getName());
                        } else {
                            dataset.addValue(chartRange.getUpperBound() - chartRange.getLowerBound(), STANDBY_SERIES, es.getName());
                        }
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        plot.setNoDataMessage("NO DATA AVAILABLE");
    }

    return dataset;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackedTimeBarChart demo = new StackedTimeBarChart("demo");
    demo.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
    demo.setVisible(true);
}

private void initData() {
      testData = new ArrayList<EventStatus>();
      testData.add(new EventStatus("Mach-1", Datetolong("03/04/2020 08:00"), 1));
      testData.add(new EventStatus("Mach-1",Datetolong("03/04/2020 09:00"), 2));
      testData.add(new EventStatus("Mach-1", Datetolong("03/04/2020 09:20"), 4));
      testData.add(new EventStatus("Mach-1", Datetolong("03/04/2020 10:00"), 3));

}
```

// Chart object class that hold category, event time and status
private class EventStatus {

```
    private String name;
    private long time;
    private int status;

    public EventStatus(String name, long time, int status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `dateAxis.setRange()` manually using the minimum and maximum `testData` dates explicitly.

Comment: Thank you I got it